# 100% mailing have bounced : validation failed for <(INVALID)>

Tags: civimail, mailing, multisite, bounce, drupal-multi-site

Hello after two modifications on the server and on CiviCRM, it becomes impossible to send any mailing. All the email adresses are "burned" with all the email addresses being wrongly tagged as bounced.
In the Report, the **Bounce Type** is for all emails indicated as **Invalid**.

**Some symptoms** : 
The table **civicrm_mailing_event_bounce** indicate for all mails adresses in the bounce_reason this problem :

`Validation failed for: "(INVALID)" <(INVALID)>`

The **bounce_type_id** in the is #6 which is **Invalid** : *Email address is not valid*
Of course the setting in admin/options/**from_email_address** (From Email Address Options) have been verified, they are OK.

In the table civicrm_mailing_bounce_pattern there is 24 different patterns from the bounce_type_id #6.

**There is then two clues** :
The server had been recently moved under PHP7.2 and CiviCRM had been enabled to handle the Multi Site Configuration with the extension CiviCRM Multisite (org.civicrm.multisite).

Did someone experimented and solved this trouble ?

Thanks for any help.

- The CMS is Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 5.4.1 on a Debian 8 server
- The bounce email boxe is located on a different Debian 8 server with Postfix Mail Server Postfix version 2.11.3

Comment: Hi Ichi - can you include more information on the actual bounce messages received to the bounce processing mailbox which is configured on your CiviCRM instance.

Comment: Arg… the bounce processing mailbox is empty ! This user has no messages in

Comment: He bounce processing system may have deleted them - depending on mail system they may be in Deleted items or otherwise ‘recoverable’

Comment: Don't you think that this means that the bounce did happen before going outside of the server ?

Comment: No, an email can’t ‘bounce’ before leaving your mail server - that would be a delivery failure which is not the same thing. Have you checked this issue with whoever manages you email system(s) - you should rule out your email system first and then it will be easier to pin down a CiviCRM or Server cause.

Comment: The mail server is different to the web server with CiviCRM. I just made a test sending direct mail to the bounce processing mailbox. Test is ok : the message arrives in the bounce processing mailbox.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what your mail server software/system is? Have you checked the deleted items in the bounce processing inbox and any mail flow/mail stats interface for your mail server - mail server logs could also shed some light.

Comment: I made an edit to the the post. Also I check the .Trash mailbox it is empty, nothing was erased…

Comment: So CiviCRM will store processed bounces in a subfolder - according to the docs - can you check the folders (including any subfolders of the inbox) to see if there are any bounce messages?

Comment: No, there is no subfolder in the Maildir apart of the classical ones. I check the spam mailbox, it's empty too.

Comment: Including subfolders of Inbox (which is where CiviCRM would create it’s folder)

Comment: No this one is empty. No folder like the one you mentioned. I see these in another bounce mailbox that was used in the past : INBOX.CiviMail.ignored and .INBOX.CiviMail.processed

Comment: It sounds like the bounce processing mailbox isn’t working correctly but It’s not an area I’m hugely familiar with - I’ll leave this one for better minds to solve :-) apologies I haven’t been of much help!

Comment: At opposite, this  help making me looking in the natural direction. But then I think that I just found the culprit in the Settings - Outbound Mail.

Comment: If you find the solution you can answer your own question :-)

Comment: Yes I just did. Thank you for your help ! This is very kind.

Comment: you should post an answer to show how you solved it - that will help other people in the future and earn you "reputation" on CiviCRM StackExchange which gives you privileges.

Comment: Ah, yes. That gonna be the 1st time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the problem.
Thanks to @HomoTechsual who lead me in the right direction.

The reason had been found in the **Settings - Outbound Mail**.
It was set to **mail()** with a success message : `Your SENDMAIL settings are correct. A test email has been sent to your email address.`
That looked good but in fact the message was never sent by the server ! Trusting this message, I did forget to check if the test email really arrived to email address. My mistake : always double check.

After I changed the setting to SMTP with all the right setting of the mail server, I still got the success message but the message arrived in the mailbox.
After I removed the bounce tag for each email address, I could make a test mailing that went fine this time ;-)

So the issue was from the mail server. The issue was not with CiviCRM. Something probably related to the DNS is not working on the server. This made CiviCRM confused about the mailing. 
From now Civimail works well with the **SMTP set** in the Settings - Outbound Mail. I the case of my server this is the only option.

UPDATE : In this case it seems that a group of several issues happened.
I found another thing that could be at the origin in the table civicrm_mailing :
both from_name and from_email are set to (INVALID)

```
from_name From Header of mailing (INVALID)
from_email From Email of mailing (INVALID)
```

Yet I have no clue how this happened but there now a clear link with `validation failed for <(INVALID)>`
I did not find why chosen email provoque that. It might be related with multi-site extension. Now I can manage the mailing with an another email address.